# Erro ao utilizar required em inputs no Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho alguns inputs do Primefaces dentro de um [Wizard](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml), mostrando apenas um deles:

```
<p:inputText id="inputTitulo" value="#{editalBean.edital.titulo}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Informe um título" label="titulo" />
```

Acontece se eu não preencher este Input, quando eu clicar no next do Wizard ele aparece a mensagem acusando o erro, mas quando eu volto a digitar, é como se as letras ficassem brancas, eu digito, as letras estão lá, mas ficam da mesma cor do fundo do input, então parece que o mesmo está em branco, mas ele preenche normal.

Resumindo, é como se eu estivesse escrevendo com a letra branca no inputText com fundo branco.

Inspeção do elemento:

https://www.diffchecker.com/4qmxuze1

Coloquei a diferença de duas inspeções, quando ainda não houve a validação, e após a validação. O tema que estou usando é o bootstrap. Quase certeza que é coisa do tema, pois troquei a cor do texto e funcionou.

Agora eis a dúvida, como mudar a cor do texto no css do tema?

Comment: Acredito que seja um problema de CSS, consegue inspecionar o elemento e verificar quais regras de CSS estão sendo aplicadas no input?

Comment: Vou verificar isso aqui @Wakim

Comment: Adicionei @Wakim, olha a diferença ai dos textos. E no state-error no segundo texto, o texto ta como branco. Como trocar no css do primefaces?

Comment: Acho que tem algum erro na regra que você  viu a diferença, deveria ficar com o fundo vermelho, crie uma regra `.ui-state-error { background-color: #cd0a0a; }` no seu CSS. Por alguma razão aquela regra esta com problemas. Não aparece nenhum warning no console de dev?

Comment: Mas como assim no meu css? Eu troquei a regra no proprio navegador. Como que faço p adicionar essa regra no css do primefaces msm?

Comment: Colocar no CSS do primefaces não é possível porque ele está dentro do jar. Você  precisa criar um arquivo CSS e importar na sua página, para sobreescrever a propriedade background-color que esta com problemas.

Comment: Hmmm, entao apenas vai sobrescrever o unico atributo. Beleza, vou pesquisar como faz isso.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que você só está com um problema de CSS. Se você não quiser criar um arquivo CSS externo, você pode fazer isso dentro da sua página mesmo:

```
<style>
    .input-color{
        color: #000000 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Ai lá no input você faz:

```
<p:inputText styleClass="input-color" ... />
```

Caso não queira criar uma classe só pra mudar a cor do texto, você pode usar a opção style do componente inputText e colocar "color: #000000 !important;"